# Yii2 build relation many to many

Tags: yii2

**Yii2 build relation many to many**

I have 2 tables users and friends
[image: tables]

Code query

```
$friends = Friends::find()
            ->select(['friends.user_id', 'users.name'])
            ->leftJoin('users','users.id = friends.friend_user')
            ->with('users')
            ->all();
```

In result error

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException.          app\models\Friends has no relation named "users".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Friends` has a column called `user_id` and thus only belongs to one user. If you auto-generated the `Friends` ActiveRecord it probably has a function `getUser` (singular because it is only one) that will look something like this:

```
public function getUser() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

So you're getting the error because no `getUsers` function exists (that returns a valid ActiveQuery object). Because there can only be one user per friend I think you should use the singular version. And if that still gives the same error you should implement the function above and maybe change it a bit to match your classname.

When you use `with(['relation'])` to load relations Yii will convert the entry to `getRelation` and call that function on the model to get the query that is needed to load the relation.

Comment: No errors, but I do not access to row related table

Comment: Ok. For access to data in views I use $all_friend->friendUser->name